# why my answer gives 1.49012e when my input is 0.1

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class deci {
    float a;
public:
    deci(float b)
    {
        a = b;
    }

    void operator-()
    {
        a = a - 0.1;
        cout << a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    float a;
    cin >> a;

    deci b(a);
    -b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just saying, the negative operator shouldn't change the object, but should return the changed object.

Comment: Your output is `1.49012e-09` which is nearly zero because `0.1f - 0.1f == 0.0f ~ 1.0e-9`

Comment: [What does E mean in 9.0122222900391E-5?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6273/what-does-e-mean-in-9-0122222900391e-5) [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Visual Studio says deci is ambiguous because it's a typedef for std::ratio<1i64, 10i64> something.

Comment: when i use double i get 0 as output i dont know what is wrong when i use float?

Comment: new to this platform thank you guys for the help!

Comment: @Zebrafish it is, if you search on CPPReference, you get `std::ratio`